# Why is content hidden for landscape page in media print

Tags: html, css, print-css

Am trying to print pages in portrait and landscape.

I have managed to get the page orientation in landscape with the following css snippet

```
 @page landscape {
   size: 9in 6in;
 }
```

But the content in landscape page seems to render in portrait.

As can be seen in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/noel3090/74y9va80/60/)

I have also marked the body css to be

```
   overflow:visible
```

Can someone guide me how the get the page content render in landscape mode for landscape page, without content getting cut.

P.S Check this in chrome

Answer (score 0):

I consider the missing property to fix your print page rendering is the ISO paper size. Please try the following snippet:

```
/* ISO Paper Size */
@page {
 size: A4 landscape;
}

/* Size in inches */    
@page {
 size: 9in 6in landscape;
}
```